# Stick footer to bottom of page without scroll afterwards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I found a tutorial on css-tricks.com for sticking a footer to the bottom of the screen/page and it works well, the only problem is, is that it is causing a scroll to occur after the footer. Its slight but very annoying.

Heres my html:

```
<div class="container content">
  <div class="row">
    content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container site-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
      <h3 class ="footer-content"></h3><br><span class="text-muted">Version {{ TAG }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

and heres my css:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px;
}
.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .content:after {
  height: 142px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Im using Bootstrap 3 aswell

Comment: What do you mean by "it is causing a scroll to occur after the footer" ? Maybe you can share a screenshot ?

Comment: Heres the codepen canvas i've been using to try and figure it out so you can see for yourself http://codepen.io/Shredivan/pen/MKEyGm

Comment: Add a css reset/normalize and remove any margins on the heading in the footer. Often in cases like this, the issue is a padding or margin on the HTML/body element and/or a heading element near the top or bottom.

Comment: I set the file up with normalize.css file in codepen and i tried removing margins and padding from it, still no luck

Comment: I added this to the top of your pen and it worked fine: *{  margin:0px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just **reset your CSS** with these lines and it wil work:

```
/* 
   http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a jsfiddle here for you. this is using your markup and I re-wrote the CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
}
.site-footer {
    height: 142px;
  background:orange;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20f751bz/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works really well in your JSFiddle and my codepen set up but when i integrate it back into my bootstrap setup on my local machine it still has the scroll afterwards. It might be something else in my style sheet affecting it.

Comment: Like the other answer says, probably some default in bootstrap that is overriding the initial * setting, so it applying padding or margin to the html/body